# How to get a module's filename or path with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generics, filenames

I'm trying to create a generic function in TS that takes a module as a parameter, has some custom logic but most importantly, at the beginning needs to either get a filename or file path from the module argument passed in.

```
    function mockModule<M>(
        module: M,
        customMocks?: Partial<MockedModule<M>>
    ): jest.Mocked<ModuleType<M>> {
        ...custom logic but I need to have the fileName or filePath of module that gets passed in     
    }
```

You would then call the function in a similar way to this from another file

```
import * as stateModule from 'Modules/jwt-state';

mockModule<typeof stateModule>(stateModule)
```

I have been reading quite a few places in the internet and see no solution, I have have even saw that there is no way if I'm using commonJS modules.

I have posted this here in case any way has a brilliant idea.

Thanks